# How do we enable SQL cache dependency in ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, sql, caching, dependencies

I think there are some steps to enable SQL Cache Depdndency :

Enabling notifications, changes in web.xml and then using Cache Dependency object.

Please help how do I pass through them ?

Comment: You are using Sql Server correct?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? The answer can be different for different versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/sql_cache_depedency_overview). It takes you through using the Aspnet_regsql.exe tool, which sets it up for you.

Here is an excerpt from the above post:

```
...To enable a cache dependency on a particular database, run this command:
aspnet_regsql.exe -S server -U user -P password -d database -ed

This creates a new table, AspNet_SqlCacheTablesForChangeNotification, 
in the designated database. Next, several AspNet_SqlCacheXxxx stored procs
are created in the same database.
```

Then look at [this post from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx) for an overview, with lots of How-to links.

Comment: FYI: This Answer applies to the old polling method. The newer notification feature of SQL Server 2005 is setup vary differently.

Answer (score 2):

To enable a *table* for SQL cache dependency use, you'll need to first run the `aspnet_regsql.exe` tool from a command-line prompt, with these options:

```
aspnet_regsql -S servername -U login -P password -ed -d databasename -et -t tablename
```

If your table name contains a space, then wrap the table name in quotes e.g.

```
aspnet_regsql -S servername -U login -P password -ed -d databasename -et -t "table name"
```

In your web.config, you'll need to add a `caching` section:

```
<system.web>
    <caching>
      <sqlCacheDependency enabled = "true" pollTime = "60000" >
        <databases>
          <add name="northwind" 
            connectionStringName="Northwind"
            pollTime="9000000"
          />
      </databases>
    </sqlCacheDependency>
  </caching>
</system.web>
```

When you add an item into your Cache, you use the SqlCacheDependency object to set up the relationship between the cached object and the underlying table:

```
SqlCacheDependency dependency = new SqlCacheDependency("databasename", "tablename");

Cache.Add(key, object, dependency);
```

Comment: how to add dependency for a table having a space in its name

Comment: thanx PhilPursglove i have tried [], '', but none of them worked thanx a lot